# Why does Grafana snapshot not match the original dashboard?

Tags: grafana

I have created a Snapshot (by selecting Share > Snapshot, see [documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/sharing/share-dashboard/)) and published to snapshot.raintank.io (which redirects to snapshots-origin.grafana.net).

According to the documenation

> A dashboard snapshot shares an interactive dashboard publicly. Grafana strips sensitive data like queries (metric, template and annotation) and panel links, leaving only the visible metric data and series names embedded into your dashboard. Dashboard snapshots can be accessed by anyone with the link.

When I open the URL, the dashboard displayed does not match my original dashboard.

This is a screenshot of the original dashboard:
[image]

These are two screenshots of the dashboard as displayed at snapshots-origin.grafana.net:

Screenshot 1 of Snapshot
[image: Screenshot 1 of Snapshot]

Screenshot 2 of Snapshot
[image: Screenshot 2 of Snapshot]

**My issues**

1. Numerical values do not match the original values (and are partially far outside the normal range).
2. The line graph in the lower half does not match (any of) the original line graph.
3. The line graph in the lower half displays only one variable out of three.
4. The bar chart in the upper right corner is missing (“Panel plugin not found: barchart”).
5. Reloading the website serves a different snapshot.

**My questions**

Is this behavior to be expected? Is the snapshot supposed to display mock data?

Otherwise: what are possible reasons for the issues observed? Is there possibly a limitation on the data volume to be hosted by snapshot.raintank.io? Are only certain graphs supported?

Answer (score 0):

A snapshot only contains the visibile data at the time you made the snapshot :) all the metric queries are removed etc...
That means this is a single point in time data visible.